# I couldn't see my extension method

Tags: c#-4.0, encryption, hash

I couldn't see this method as extension method in MainWindow.xaml.cs , why

In MainWindow , 
I added : 
    using WpfApplication1_WPF.Classes;

please, advise me.

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Data.Objects;

namespace WpfApplication1_WPF.Classes
{
public static class Extensions 
{
      //1-Convert the user input to hash 
      public static String Hashed(String dataToHash)
      {
         //Convert dataToHash to byte array
         byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(dataToHash);

         //Computer hash of bytes using SHA256 (256 bit hash value)
         //Convert text to hash by using ComputerHash function in SHA256Managed algorithm
         byte[] hash = new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(plainTextBytes);

         //Return hashed bytes as encoded string 
         //[convert hash byte to string to be saved in DB]
         return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to include the `this` keyword by the parameter which you wish the extension method to apply to (i.e. dataToHash in this case).  Also, check that you've referenced the project containing your code in addition to your using statement (i.e. if the class is not part of the same project).

Comment: Thank you John for your explanation, appreciate your help and your support  [TGH][JohnLBevan]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the signarure

```
public static String Hashed(this String dataToHash)
```

You need the `this` in front of the input param.

Comment: You did my day, Thank you [TGH][JohnLBevan]